# How to run python apps on a shared host with no bash or console command prompt privileges?

Tags: python, shared-hosting

I want to run a python app called Flask on shared hosting but I don't have access to bash or command prompt or ssh but I am provided with:

[image: **lol! can't embed image yet - image**]

Well, that's okay! Let me explain what I see in case the image cant be seen

**Configuration files**:  A button that says **RUN PIP INSTALL**

A text field that says: **Enter another file and press enter**

**Environment variables** and an **ADD** button.

I know how to do this on my local machine

```
pip install flask
```

But how do I do it on the shared hosting?

I have a virtual environment that is just a folder but I can't access it since no ssh but it looks like

[image: additional information image]

Comment: Use a better hosting provider. There are plenty that allow you to run Python apps.

Comment: This seems like a question best asked of your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have figured it out and I want to share my experience here.

step 1.
on the cpanel, scroll and find python under software and click it.

step 2.
creat application

select python version

application root is where you will upload your data

Application startup file is and should be: **init**.py

Application Entry point will be: application

Passenger log file: blog.log

click create

step 3
open passenger_wsgi.py and type:

import os
import sys

from **init** import app as application

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(**file**))

save

step 4

creat you app on your lacal machine and pip freeze all requirement

copy the requirement.txt files and upload it to your application root folder and

click python again from your cpanel software and click edit your application

on Configuration files, type your requirement .txt and click add

then keep building your app on your lacal machine and upload your files they will run

Answer (score 0):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=260eDcsUheE) was the best tutorial I could find on how to properly configure a shared host (cPanel/Phusion Passenger) to work with Flask.

The only other thing I do to avoid the importlib nagging warning

> DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of
> importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses

is to change the default `passenger_wsgi.py` contents to

```
from app import app as application
```

Beware that this file might be rewritten when changing the application through the cPanel page.